# How to redirect from one page to another one with changing wp query and without reloading page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

**The problem**

There is a URL:
https://example.com/my-category/category

Need to create another one
https://example.com/shop

**Behavior to achieve:**

By visiting https://example.com/shop content and all query variables need to be identical like for https://example.com/my-category/category

https://example.com/my-category/category and https://example.com/shop - need to be the same. 
Meta tags, title, and other content need to be identical.

Need to create an inner redirect

from https://example.com/shop

to https://example.com/my-category/category without reloading page.

**This is the snippet what I've tried**

`flush_rewrite_rules();
add_rewrite_rule(
  '/shop?$',
  'index.php?product_cat=my-category',
  'top'
);`

I expect to see the same page for these two URLs

https://example.com/my-category/category
and
https://example.com/shop

The second one needs to be redirected to the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution via `request` filter

```
function example_rewrite_request($query){
    $request_uri = urldecode( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );

    $parsed_url = parse_url( $request_uri );

    if (  preg_match( '/^\/shop/', $parsed_url['path'] ) ) {
        $query['product_cat'] = 'my-category';
        unset( $query['post_type'] );

        return $query;
    }

    return $query; 
}
```

`add_filter( 'request', 'example_rewrite_request', 9999, 1 );`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this is to edit your `.htaccess` file (on your server, at the root folder for http://example.com) and add a [301 Redirect](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/301-redirects/) as follows:

```
Redirect 301 /shop /my-category/category
```

This means that when someone enters `http://www.example.com/shop` in the browser, it will be automatically redirected to `http://www.example.com/my-category/category`, and latter page will load.